# Modify a variable in target Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Have been searching for days and didn't find an answer or it didn't work for me.

I've built home alarm system with Raspberry Pi and PIR sensor.
The alarm system consists of **control.py** and **alarm.py** scripts.
The **control.py** is simple flask webpage for controlling alarm detection.
The **alarm.py** is basicaly a while loop that checks if the sensor has been trigered.

I'm starting **alarm.py** with Popen from **control.py**. Is there a way to modify a variable in **alarm.py** from **control.py** (so that the while loop breaks and program exits)?

Line of code in control.py that starts a detection program:

```
detection = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'alarm.py'], shell=False)
```

And the loop in alarm.py:

```
while True:


    CurrentState=GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

    if CurrentState==1 and PreviousState==0:
        print "Motion detected!"
        PreviousState=1
    elif CurrentState==1 and PreviousState==1:
        print "Motion detected!"
    elif CurrentState==0 and PreviousState==1:
        PreviousState=0

    time.sleep(0.1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Can you include the code (at least reverent snippets) from `alarm.py` and `control.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting alarm.py as a separate process, there is no shared variable space for directly setting any variable from control.py that alarm.py can access.

You have a few options here:

- Use [threads](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html) instead of subprocessing
- Use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module which provides mechanisms for communication between two Python processes
- Attach stdin of your alarm.py subprocess to a pipe and attempt a non-blocking read on each iteration of the loop, write to that pipe from control.py when you are ready to exit
- Use some OS level modification as the signal for alarm.py to exit (for example, the creation of a file in a specific location)

Comment: I actually got it working by writing a string to a file from control.py and then in alarm.py within a loop opening this file, reading and assigning it to a varible and then closing the file. The variable would then break the loop and the program exits. But it seems to me that this is a rather dirty solution and also accessing a file repeatedly may damage flash memory. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nothing dirty about it, especially on a locked down system like Raspberry Pi where you know the file won't be deleted by some careless user or another process.  This is more or less what my 4th bullet point suggests.

Comment: @Muhc: it *is* rather dirty e.g., it involves unnecessary polling and you have to worry about cleaning up the file. Almost any IPC method will do instead e.g., just call `detection.terminate()`